# Issue using ff with SVM function in library(e1071)

Tags: r, svm, ff

I am trying to use a ff object to run a svm classification study.

I converted my dataframe to a ff object using ffdf <- as.ffdf(signalDF).  The dataset has 1024 columns and ~ 600K rows.

When I run the function, `svm(Y~., data=ffdf,scale=FALSE,kernel="linear")`, I receive the error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.8 Gb

Running ulimit -n:
64000
```

Also, runnning df shows plenty of disk space.

Any reason why I am receiving a memory error when using a ff object?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Disk space is different from memory available for computation. The error indicates that you don't have enough memory to perform the computation. Major reasons are that your data set is large and your computer has limited RAM. If you reduce the training size it will run.